# Return function returns nothing

Tags: javascript, function, return

I am using this function in js(it should return the special subject) :

```
function getSubjectByNumber(subject_number) {

  var subject_name;

  if (subject_number === 0) {
    return subject_name = "Deutsch";
  }
  if (subject_number === 1) {
    return subject_name = "Englisch";
  }
  if (subject_number === 2) {
    return subject_name = "Latein";
  }
  if (subject_number === 3) {
    return subject_name = "Kunst";
  }
  if (subject_number === 4) {
    return subject_name = "Musik";
  }
  if (subject_number === 5) {
    return subject_name = "Instrument/G. (Additum)";
  }
  if (subject_number === 6) {
    return subject_name = "Französisch (spät.)";
  }
  if (subject_number === 7) {
    return subject_name = "Theater und Film";
  }
  ..//That goes a long time...
}
```

And I call the return method with this code line:

```
var subject_name = getSubjectByNumber(subject);
```

But as I see it returns nothing (''), because the var `subject_name` stays always empty. I hope anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.
~mb

Comment: What is the value of `subject` when you call the function? Also the `subject_name` variable in your function really does not do anything; you could just return the strings directly. Better yet, create an object (or array) to map the numbers to the string, and then your function would be one line long.

Comment: please add a value of `subject`. btw, an array woud be better to use.

Comment: What is `subject`? If it's a string, that would explain it because `===` doesn't do any type conversion so, `"0" === 0` would be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the strict equality operator (`===`), which doesn't do any type conversion on the operands. If `subject` is a String, then that would explain it because `"0" === 0` is `false`. In this scenario, you need to either convert `subject` to a number (just prepending `+` to it would do it) or use `==` to do an equality with conversion check.

**But, all your `if/then` logic as well as the string/number issue can be eliminated if you just use an array.**

```js
let subjects = ["Deutsch", "Englisch", "Latein", "Kunst", "Musik", "Instrument/G. (Additum)", "Französisch (spät.)", "Theater und Film"];

function getSubjectByNumber(subject_number) {
  return subjects[subject_number];
}

console.log(getSubjectByNumber(0));
console.log(getSubjectByNumber("0"));
console.log(getSubjectByNumber(6));
console.log(getSubjectByNumber(7));
```

Comment: How I get this to work when I have "0" instead of 0?

Comment: @marcelo.wdrb As I mentioned in my answer, that no longer matters when you use an array and you can see that in my example as I am running it with `"0"` and `0` and it correctly returns `Deutsch` in both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider an array.

A coercion is not even needed so just do the following - as you can see the 0 and "0" work the same

```js
function getSubjectByNumber(subject_number) {
  return ["Deutsch","Englisch","..."][subject_number] || "not found";
}

console.log(
 0,   getSubjectByNumber(0),
 "0", getSubjectByNumber("0"),
 1, getSubjectByNumber(1),
 10, getSubjectByNumber(10) // not found
);
```

Comment: But, how to get it to work when I have "0" instead of 0?

Comment: no need to convert to number, because keys are always strings, even for arrays.

Comment: @NinaScholz I thought so, but decided to wear braces AND suspenders. Anyway updated